# for loop iterates strange

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good Morning,
I have a problem with for loop, I tried to make multiply progressbars on page and I try to triger them in one action:

```
function startProgressbaring(){

var progressArray = [ 
    progress1 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-1'),
    progress2 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-2'),
    progress3 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-3'),
    progress4 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-4'),
    progress5 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-5'),
    progress6 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-6')
];
var durationArray = [ 
     progress1_Duration = 90,
     progress2_Duration = 65,
     progress3_Duration = 70,
     progress4_Duration = 55,
     progress5_Duration = 95,
     progress6_Duration = 90
];

var id = setInterval(frame,30);
var width = 1;





        function frame(){
        for(var z=0; z<durationArray.length; z++){  

            if(width>durationArray[z]){
                clearInterval(id);
                console.log(durationArray[z]);
            }else {
                width++;
                progressArray[z].style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }

        };
```

Console Log with durationArray returns only 55, for example
six progressbars have values between 56 and 60 not the values from durationArray,
no idea whats going wrong, thanks for any advices

Comment: You know that you could simply do durationArray=[90,65,70...] ?

Comment: I forgot this:-, but this make no difference

Comment: Because as soon as width is 56, you clear the timer, frame() won't be called again after that round of for loop finishes iterating

Comment: Artur, is there anything stopping you from accepting our answers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you do

```
clearInterval(id);
```

if one of the frames reaches its width. That automatically stops the others too. May just stop if all have ended:

```
function frame(){
 var running=false;
 for(var z=0; z<durationArray.length; z++){  
        if(width>durationArray[z]){
            console.log(durationArray[z]);
        }else {
            running=true;
            width++;
            progressArray[z].style.width = width + '%';
       }         
  }
  if(!running) clearInterval(id);
};
```

Comment: Im trying understand why if condition is needed there, I dont need the console.log, when I erase it thats ok, I just not to put logs and the statement is empty, when I erase if statement from "if to }"  else statement runs infinitely can you explain it?

Comment: @artur Juzwik you still need an if. You could negate that (!) though...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, but the code can be explained. You are not setting the width of your progress bars to any values in `durationArray`, you are setting your progress bars to the width value: `progressArray[z].style.width = width + '%';`. `width` will eventually be larger than the smallest value in the `durationArray`. When this happens, you stop the interval with `clearInterval`. `width` will increase a couple more times while `for` loop iterates for the last time.

Answer (score 0):

add a single line of logging to your code and observer the output (see below).
Basicall what happens is:

1. your width starts with value 1, and increases with each iteration
2. after iterating over the 6 item array 9 times, the value of width is
   54
3. your iteration reaches progress4_Duration with width = 58 (54 + 4)
4. width > durationArray[z] condition will be true, interval gets cleared, processing stops.

Assuming you only need to stop the iteration for a particular progressbar, probably you need an array of process ids and only stop the one that has sufficent width.

```
function startProgressbaring(){

    var progressArray = [ 
        progress1 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-1'),
        progress2 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-2'),
        progress3 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-3'),
        progress4 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-4'),
        progress5 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-5'),
        progress6 = document.querySelector('.progressbar-6')
    ];
    var durationArray = [ 
         progress1_Duration = 90,
         progress2_Duration = 65,
         progress3_Duration = 70,
         progress4_Duration = 55,
         progress5_Duration = 95,
         progress6_Duration = 90
    ];

    var intervalArray = [];
    durationArray.forEach(function(d) {
        intervalArray.push(setInterval(frame,1000))
    });

    //var id = setInterval(frame,1000);
    var width = 1;

    function frame(){
        for(var z=0; z<durationArray.length; z++){  

            // debug output
            //console.log(width, durationArray[z]);

            if(width>durationArray[z]){
                //clearInterval(id);
                clearInterval(intervalArray[z]);
                console.log(durationArray[z]);
            } else {
                width++;
                progressArray[z].style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }
    }
}
```